# MYSQL SELECT unexpected result

Tags: mysql

`Test` table in the database looks like

```
id - int
title - varchar
```

```
+---+-------+
| id| title |
+---+-------+
|1  | name  |
+---+-------+
```

I run the query
`` SELECT * FROM `Test` WHERE id="1abc" ``

Then it gives the output as

```
+---+-------+
|1  | name  |
+---+-------+
```

Comment: That's becouse  `id` is integer, so, `"1abc"` will be convert to `1`

Comment: but  "1abc" is not an integer

Comment: [`1 = '1', ' 1', or '1a'`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Type Declared in `ID` is an `Integer`.

when you pass in a `string` beginning with a `number`, it would assume you are tyring to input a `number` value. Thus converting the value to an `integer` (the first letter in your `string`)

the warning message would appear as something like

> Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: "1abc"

[Type Conversion Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)

Comment: Also to add, if you run `select convert('13deee2rf' , unsigned int);` it will return you 13. hopefully this is clear